# Regarding Image paths of a page using master page

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

If the Master Page and child aspx page are in different folders, when the aspx page is served, whether image paths are relative to the location of child page or the Master page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child page.

Consider using the "~/" in your path which points to the application root, that way you can set your images in your master page to something like "~/images/image_name.png" without worrying about where the child pages are stored.